# How to refresh/update a variable in Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I have this Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib -lgcc
BUILD_DIR = ../build
BIN = $(BUILD_DIR)/os.bin
LINKER_SCRIPT = linker.ld
OBJ_FILES := $(shell find $(BUILD_DIR) -iname '*.o')

.PHONY: all

all:
    @make -C boot
    @make -C kernel
    $(CC) -T $(LINKER_SCRIPT) -o $(BIN) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES)
```

After compiling (doing make in boot and kernel directories) there should be files with .o extension, however OBJ_FILES is empty. Only after calling make again OBJ_FILES contains the .o files paths which are needed to link. So my question is how do I update OBJ_FILES after compiling in the boot and kernel directories, because OBJ_FILES doesn't update/refresh.

Comment: Please read [ask].  Were any errors or warnings emitted on the first build attempt?  If so, what were they?  [Edit] your post to include the exact invocation and resulting output.

Comment: You should rethink your concept. It is not a good idea to assume *all .o* files lying in the directory should be linked to the kernel. Perhaps produce an `.a` in each of the nested makefiles?

Comment: I agree with both Beta and Antti that there are probably better ways to do this, but to solve the problem you asked about in the most straightforward way all you have to do is _stop_ using simple variable assignment (`:=`) and make's `shell` function, and switch to recursive variable assignment and shell replacement: `OBJ_FILES = $$(find $(BUILD_DIR) -iname '*.o')`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have following structure:

```
.
|-- Makefile
|-- boot
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- boot.c
|   `-- boot.h
|-- kernel
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- kernel.c
|   `-- kernel.h
`-- main.c
```

and your `Makefile` looks like this

```
location = $(CURDIR)

OBJ_FILES = $(shell find $(location) -name '*.o')

all: make_common
        gcc -o main main.c $(OBJ_FILES)

make_common:
        @make -C boot
        @make -C kernel

clean:
        -rm boot/boot.o
        -rm kernel/kernel.o
```

Your source code is quite simple:

```
> cat boot/boot.h
int boot();

> cat boot/boot.c
int boot() {
  return 1;
}

> cat kernel/kernel.h
int kernel();

> cat kernel/kernel.c
int kernel() {
  return 2;
}

> cat main.c
#include "boot/boot.h"
#include "kernel/kernel.h"

int main() {
  int result = boot() + kernel();
  return 0;
}
```

"inner" `Makefile`s contain

```
> cat boot/Makefile
all:
    gcc -c boot.c

> cat kernel/Makefile
all:
    gcc -c kernel.c
```

you will get what you are looking for

```
> make clean
rm boot/boot.o
rm: boot/boot.o: No such file or directory
make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)
rm kernel/kernel.o
rm: kernel/kernel.o: No such file or directory
make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)
> make
gcc -c boot.c
gcc -c kernel.c
gcc -o main main.c ..../boot/boot.o ..../kernel/kernel.o
```

---

```
VAR = val
```

Expanded when the variable is used.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is how do I update `OBJ_FILES` after compiling in the boot and kernel directories, because `OBJ_FILES` doesn't update/refresh.

`OBJ_FILES` variable won't change its value once make started executing the rules.

See [3.7 How make Reads a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) for full details:

> GNU make does its work in two distinct phases. During the first phase it reads all the makefiles, included makefiles, etc. and internalizes all the variables and their values and implicit and explicit rules, and builds a dependency graph of all the targets and their prerequisites. During the second phase, make uses this internalized data to determine which targets need to be updated and run the recipes necessary to update them.
>
> It’s important to understand this two-phase approach because it has a direct impact on how variable and function expansion happens; this is often a source of some confusion when writing makefiles.

What you can do instead is restart `make` once it built kernel and boot:

```
all: $(BIN)

$(BIN) : $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) -T $(LINKER_SCRIPT) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES)

Makefile :
    @$(MAKE) -C boot
    @$(MAKE) -C kernel
    touch $@ # <---- Causes the Makefile to be re-read.

.PHONY: all
```